# Access phone camera with a button (HTML)

Tags: html

I'm developing a application that needs to access the phone camera. I'm currently using the Ratchet Framework but that's not really relevant here.

I have a button that needs to open the camera onClick. I know that to access the camera we need this:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" onChange="updatePhoto(event);"></input>
```

And my button is like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-positive btn-block"> Choose photo </button>
```

I tried putting the input to access the camera inside the button but it doesn't make the ugly "Choose photo" disappear making it look silly. I just need to replace the standard "Choose photo" that appears when we put only the first input and replace it with the button to look better.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but that is not possible. That's like sending a notification from your website. You are only going to get somewhere with other methods like jailbreaking, exploiting a software vulnerability (not recommended if you are releasing your website to the public) or creating an app (way much better) for example.

You need more access to a phone to be able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

accessing phone is much simplier with cordova, since all packaged. You build one code with cordova / ionic and that will generate all apps you needs for your plateform.

Use cordova /ionic for that, this framework have prebuild camera plugins.

See documentation : https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera/

This is easy and powerfull.

here is some code :

```
this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
 // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
 // If it's base64:
 let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
}, (err) => {
 // Handle error
});`
```

(please take a look at this post also, to see that it will be a difficult way in order to integrate phones components with rachet https://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/03/21/avoid-ratchet-for-phonegapcordova-development)